# std::vector with initial size explicitly set to 0

Tags: c++, c++11

Will following C++ code be standard compliant if `size` remains `0`?

```
std::size_t size = 0;
//... some code that may change size
auto foo = std::vector<int>(size);
```

Or do I have to resort to something like this:

```
std::size_t size = 0;
//... some code that may change size
auto foo = [size]() {
  if (size > 0) return std::vector<int>(size);
  else return std::vector<int>();
}();
```

Comment: `std::vector<int> foo(size); foo.emplace_back(0); foo.emplace_back(1); ... ` ???

Comment: Yes, you can create an empty vector.

Comment: Are you asking whether `size == 0` is a valid value for the std::vector constructor? Yes, it is.

Comment: @freakish yup, that's what I am asking. If you could give source it would be cool

Comment: @bartop https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector What is not prohibited, is allowed.

Comment: Also https://eel.is/c++draft/vector#cons-4

Comment: It would make no sense if you were allowed to create an empty vector only by default and not by specifying the size. Would you also suspect that `some_vector.resize(0)` could be invalid?

Comment: I would observe that the `count` parameter to the vector constructor has an unsigned type. That tells me two things. 1) Someone realized that negative values make no sense, so they are prohibited. 2) That same someone did not prohibit zero. *The second point does not mean a lot if the someone is just learning the language, but someone defining the language can be held to a higher standard.*